# Ray only works up and down and not left and right?

Tags: game-engine, logic-bricks

I have an empty that is alwas at the center of the screen (on an object). If you do not understand that, look at my previous questions relating to it. My ray that goes from the camera to whatever object in the center of the screen is having an issue. It only works up and down and not left and right. I tried changing the axis on which it points at and then works left and right in addition to up and down. I am just asking the following: does axis have any other side effects other than the way it points? Thanks!